# How do I spoof a url for debugging purposes?

Tags: firefox, internet, debug

I want to replace the source of a URL with another one (for example, replace a .js file reading "alert(1)" with "alert(2)"). Are there any tools that allow me to spoof the source of a URL for some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With development tools you can change the source of the currently displayed page. To change some referenced file, the easiest way is probably to download the file, patch it, and point the link in the current page to the local location of the file.

In Chrome, Ctrl + Shift + I opens the development tool view, where you can directly manipulate your local copy of the website:

[image]

It looks like you can also manipulate the scripts directly there, but if that doesn't work, my first approach should. In the tab "elements" you see the html code, you can search for the script file you want to change and replace the reference.

Comment: yeah... but how?

Comment: @thanoschimichan-ga Does my edit answer your question about how?